# What information say $\alpha''(s)$ .

Tags: geometry

What information say $\alpha''(s)$ when a path is parametrized for arc longitude.

I know that as $\alpha$ is parametrize by arc longitude then $|\alpha'(s)|=1$ then
if i derived $\alpha'(s)\alpha''(s)=0$ so $\alpha'(s)$ is orthogonal to $\alpha''(s)$.
Then what information give me $|\alpha''(s)|$. I am confused because i want to know explicitly what it tells me different to speak about the variation of the velocities in a path. Excuse me if my question no has sense, i would like to understand a meaning graph and conceptual please. Thank you

Comment: In short: $\kappa(s)=\|\alpha''(s)\|$ is a [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#In_terms_of_arc-length_parametrization).

Comment: Thank you @KurtG.